# How to scale a range of numbers in javascript so that integers in the middle ranges become greater and the outer limit numbers remain unchanged

Tags: javascript, math, range

I have a bunch of users taking a poll, and I want to visualize those results on screen via some circles that change size according to % of people who voted for the answer. What currently happens is that, because you won't likely have 100% of people all voting for the same answer (most answers come in,say, at the 10-40% range) - the change in size doesn't appear that great. But if I adjust the scale of the circles for this, then if respondents would actually all vote for the same answer, the circle would be way too big.

I need a way to scale these numbers, so that those middle ranges of numbers become more greatly accentuated toward their outer ranges (so, a 10% might look closer in size to a 0%, and a 40% might look closer to a 100%.

How would I do this? Anyone know the function (or even mathematical concept). My arithmetic is rusty...

Comment: Please close this question and ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/. You can then take the mathematical concept that you get from there and apply it to JS.

Comment: I got abused on the math stack exchange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should decide first what the max circle size can be.   Then base the percentages off that.

For example, if the diameter of the max circle is 100 pixels, then what is 40 pct of that max?

Or to make the biggest pct occupy 100 pct of the max you could then divide the max pixels (100) by your max pct (40).  So 100/40=2.5

Now you could scale all circles 2.5 times their normal size.

Comment: I think this gets me close. The only thing is, the scaling amount should be a logical and predictable distribution - meaning, a 100% response rate would always look bigger than a 40% response rate, but that 40% response rate, since it tends to be on the higher range for a typical response, would be bigger than just 40% of the max pixel size (40px).

Comment: Then don't perform the zoom scaling